# Quick question about a proof of the theorem: If $N$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ of index $2$, then $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, normal-subgroups

I have a minor question about a proof of the following standard theorem in group theory

> Theorem: If $N$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ of index $2$, then $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

It is the beginning portion of the proof that I have some questions.  The beginning of the proof I have in mind goes as follows:

> "Let $a\in G$, since $[G:N]=2$, then there are two cosets of $G$.  So we can further assume that $a\notin N$, hence $aN\neq N$ and so $N\cap aN=\emptyset$..."

So my question are as follows: even though $N\cap aN=\emptyset$, it is still true that $|N|=|aN|$ just like in a proof of Lagrange's theorem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $f:N\to aN$ $$f(n) =an$$ is a bijection

Comment: @SouravGhosh because it is a bijection, i can conclude the two cosets maps bijectively to each other, I can conclude that they have the same cardinality even though they are not equal as sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a\in G$. The function

$$\begin{align}
\lambda_a:N&\to aN,\\
n&\mapsto an
\end{align}$$

has inverse

$$\begin{align}
\lambda_{a^{-1}}:aN&\to N,\\
n&\mapsto a^{-1}n.
\end{align}$$

It is thus a bijection.

Therefore, $|N|=|aN|$ by definition.

Comment: thanks.  I always thought the way that proof is written out is weird.  I wonder if $a\notin N$,, then can we let $G=aN\cup bN$ where $a\neq b$ instead of just writing $G=N\cup bN$

Comment: You're welcome, @SethMai. If you found it helpful, please consider upvoting :)

Comment: No, @SethMai; we have $N=nN$ for all $n\in N$ though.

Comment: ah ok ok.  So if i write instead $G=aN\cup bN$, with $a\neq b$, we would end up having $(ab)^{-1}N(ab)\subset N$ as a conclusion.

Comment: Not necessarily, @SethMai. Just because $a\neq b$, it doesn't mean $aN\neq bN$.

Comment: it was assume that $a\notin N$ so if i imitate the steps of Lagrange's theorem won't I need to have another element $b\in G$ where $a\neq b$ and $aN\cap bN=\emptyset$.  I mean the reason in the proof of Lagrange theorem, where $|G| = |a_1N|+|a_2N| + \dots + |a_nN|$ where all the $a_i\in G$ and $N$ is a subgroup of $G$, includes the case that one of the $a_i=e$ the identity element of $G$.  Is that correct?

Comment: You will end up concluding $b\in N$, @SethMai.

Comment: ah kk.  I will try to work that out. IF i have trouble, I will come back here and let you know.  Thank you again.

Comment: You're better off asking a new question, @SethMai.

Answer (score 2):

There's a natural bijection between the elements of $N$ and the elements of $aN$ given by $\phi(g)= a\cdot g$ where $(\cdot)$ is the group multiplication. It's a good exercise to prove this map is indeed a bijection (hint: use the fact $a$ has an inverse). From that it follows the cosets have the same size.

Comment: I know how to show the bijection part.  As I have respond to Shaun, instead of having $G=N\cup bN$, can't we have $G=aN\cup bN$ for $a\neq b$ instead.